# how to validate a input field in jquery or javascript with only indian mobile number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to validate the input field with only indian mobile number and the input field should contain 91 at the beginning when the try to type a mobile number on the input and this input should not exceed more than 10 digit after 91.so if anyone can help me with jquery or javascript validation in this.

```
<input id="mobileNumber" onkeypress="mobileValidation()" type="number">

  function mobileValidation()
    {
        var mobile = document.getElementById('mobileNumber').value;
        var regex = (/^91/.test(mobile) && (mobile.length<13));
        return regex;
    }

But what i want that it should show 91 at the starting when press any key on that input field.
```

Comment: Can you give examples?

Comment: yes just checkout this website https://paytm.com/ and go to login and check how it works.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What did you try to solve this issue 
and what problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateMobile(){
  var mobile=document.getElementById("mobile").value;
  
  // caclulate a boolean result:
  var result=(/^91/.test(mobile) && (mobile.length<13));

  //Do what you want with result      
  alert(result);
}
```

```html
<input id="mobile">
<input type="submit" value="validate" onclick="validateMobile()">
```